# How can i make wine more secure (or idiot proof)

Tags: wine

I wonder if it's ever possible to 'secure' wine; like for a user not being able to delete 'explorer.exe' or mess with the dll's.

I've heard of apparmor (i'm running ubuntu), and chroot.

What would be the best method ?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this: set the files to a different user (`chown`), and set the "group" and "other" rights to "read only" (`chmod 644`).

That way, the current user can only read the files, but not modify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filesystem permissions of the host OS to "secure" the files.